# How to store processed file in users desktop?

Tags: php

I have created a website.In that scaling an image option is created.. Now i want to store that scaled  image in users desktop..But its saving in code existing folder..
Please help me by sending php script to store that file in desktop

Answer (score 6):

If your website is going to actually live on the web instead of on people's computers locally then you can't directly save it to their computer. You can serve it to them with php as a file download by setting the proper mime-type and content headers (using `header()`) followed by the file itself, or better yet offer the user a download link so they can choose to download it themselves.

If your website is going to be used locally (a little odd, but it could happen), then you can use `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()` in php to work with local files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do this without asking for user intervention on where to save the processed file. If you think about it, it would be a significant security flaw if a web server could arbitrarily save files to user desktops!

The best you could do is set the content header of the generated file to have a content disposition of attachment and then the browser will prompt the user where to save the file.